# Completing associated work items after merging - possible to configure which state work items are changed to?

Tags: merge, workitem

[Complete associated work items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy7d7.jpg)
When this functionality is Activated I would like to configure which state the linked workitems are moved/changed

Are there any possibilities for me to configure what happens to the work items that are associated?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the work item state associated with the PR by prefixing the work item with the appropriate state.
Example PR Description:

```
Fixed user state error
Resolved: #211
```

More information in the following page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/auto-complete-work-items-pull-requests?view=azure-devops#specify-the-workflow-state-of-linked-work-items